# Rendering template using iron:router in package (Meteor 1.3)

Tags: cordova, meteor, meteor-packages

i ran into a problem that i still don't understand... using iron:router inside a package (using meteor 1.3)

Indeed, when i start my application this is shown in the web.browser

> Couldn't find a template named "home" or "home". Are you sure you defined it?

This is the package.js file i wrote so far

```
Package.onUse(function(api) {
    api.versionsFrom('1.3.2.4');
    api.use(['templating'], 'client');
    api.use([
        'iron:router@1.0.12',
        'fortawesome:fontawesome',
        'momentjs:moment',
        'materialize:materialize',
    ], ['client']);

    api.addFiles('javascript/routes.js', ['web.browser']);

    api.addAssets([
        'view/home.html',
        'stylesheet/main.css',
    ], ['web.browser']);
});
```

and the routes.js file (nothing to complicated here as the Template in the html file)

```
Router.route('/', function () {
  this.render('home');
});
```

I have tested many things aren't working so far, i think i miss something (maybe obvious but.. still).

Can someone help me ?

The whole purpose is to separate my project into 2 packages (one load for web.browser and the other for web.cordova).

Comment: Is there a `<template name='home'>` in `view/home.html`?

Comment: Yes, basic one with just a <h1> tag in there